# Person structured-data missing name?

Tags: structured-data

I have this on my page:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <a href="john.html" itemprop="url">John W</a>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <a href="chloe_m.html" itemprop="url">Chloe M</a>
</div>
...
```

But all my items have errors: Missing: name

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add an element with `itemprop="name"`, like so:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <a href="john.html" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="name">John W</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <a href="chloe_m.html" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="name">Chloe M</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Have a look at the microdata examples at the bottom of [this page](http://schema.org/Person)